# PostGIS St_AsGeoBuf: how to handle Boolean type?

Tags: postgis, mapbox

I am using `ST_AsGeoBuf` function in a query like that one:

```sql
SELECT ST_AsGeoBuf(t.*, 'geom') 
FROM table t
```

After decoding the geobuf to a legible JSON the boolean types show up as strings with values "f" or "t".

I also tested encoding and decoding GeoJSONs with Boolean attributes and it worked properly, so now I know that the issue lies within PostGIS and not the decoder or the format. I need to get a geobuf with proper Boolean types. Any workarounds for this?

PostGIS v3.0

Comment: Cast the column to `TEXT` (or `INT`) on-the-fly before passing the record to the function.

Comment: I want to have a Boolean value in the geobuf without any conversions. At the moment the function works, but true/false values are automatically converted to strings 't' and 'f'. I know I can cast it to `int` or `text` but it causes an inconsistency in app logic, so I'd rather avoid that